# find user identity

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

Is it possible to detect user identity from browser using asp.net/vb.net/c# except IP address. My aim is to detect user visit count regardless of IP address; may be Mac address or etc?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get more than just user identity from request object

```
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;


        string browserInfo =
             "RemoteUser=" + context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"] + ";\n"
            + "RemoteHost=" + context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_HOST"] + ";\n"
            + "Type=" + context.Request.Browser.Type + ";\n"
            + "Name=" + context.Request.Browser.Browser + ";\n"
            + "Version=" + context.Request.Browser.Version + ";\n"
            + "MajorVersion=" + context.Request.Browser.MajorVersion + ";\n"
            + "MinorVersion=" + context.Request.Browser.MinorVersion + ";\n"
            + "Platform=" + context.Request.Browser.Platform + ";\n"
            + "SupportsCookies=" + context.Request.Browser.Cookies + ";\n"
            + "SupportsJavaScript=" + context.Request.Browser.EcmaScriptVersion.ToString() + ";\n"
            + "SupportsActiveXControls=" + context.Request.Browser.ActiveXControls + ";\n"
            + "SupportsJavaScriptVersion=" + context.Request.Browser["JavaScriptVersion"] + "\n";
```

You can access user identity by:

```
context.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"]
```

or

```
User.Identity.Name
```